# Inverse Fourier transform in matlab for amplitude

Tags: matlab

I have an image which is the amplitude of the Fourier transformation. I tried `ifft` but it does't work (I have a black image). So how can I do this?

I get this message:

```
Warning: Displaying real part of complex input.
```

This is a piece of my code:

```
F=fft2(img);
F = fftshift(F);
F = abs(F);
F = log(F+1);
F = mat2gray(F);
F=ifft2(F);
imshow(F)
```

The idea is to take a picture of me and to do a Fourier transformation of it. Next, I cut the center of the Fourier transformation. I want to see how my picture looks like.

Comment: You try to view complex values by real command. Can you add piece of code?

Comment: What function gives you that warning?

Comment: Sorry to be late i didn't see your comments (i'm new in this website and also in matlab) in fact what i want to do is to take a picture of me and to do the fourier transform of it after that i cut the center of the fourier transform and i want to see how my picture look like this is the idea for the peace of code:B=fft2(img);
>> F = fftshift(F); 
F = abs(F); 
F = log(F+1);
F = mat2gray(F);
 ifft2(F);and imshow(F)

Comment: @user2539972     You were supposed to have some matrix manipulation operation, as you mentioned that you need to cut the centre of your image. Where did you do that?

Comment: I did it but it was successful so i didn't put it in this code.It's just a piece of code.

Comment: You have some mistakes. First, you should pick different variables for each step in your code, so you can trace and catch things that happened somewhere along the way. Second, you can save lines and variables by `F=abs(fftshift(fft2(img)));`, etc. But the meaningful mistakes are the line `ifft2(F)` that you didn't put it to any variable as input (so it probably exist in  "ans"), and also what's the meaning of mat2gray in the frequency domain, if you interesting in the space domain? You should do it after ifft2, but i don't think it necessary at all.

Comment: Even with your remarks the problem still persist and I think you're aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just got the order wrong, let me know if this work

```
img = imread('whatever.png');
F = abs(fft2(img));
F = log10(1+F); 
F= fftshift(F);
imshow(F,[]);
```